# Which rack environment do cucumber features run in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, rack

I can suppress Rack::Timeout logger messages in Rspec by putting the following into my spec helper:

```
Rack::Timeout.unregister_state_change_observer(:logger) if ENV['RACK_ENV'] == 'test'
```

But if I want this to work in features/support/env.rb, then I need to remove the if statement. So I'm guessing that cucumber does not run in the test environment. What does it do instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses `RAILS_ENV` instead of `RACK_ENV`.

In my `env.rb` file I just had it output the `ENV` variable. Do this to double check, but in mine I clearly see:

```
"RAILS_ENV"=>"test"
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the correct answer, and the following code in application.rb fixes this problem: `Rack::Timeout.unregister_state_change_observer(:logger) if ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == 'test'`. Thanks.

Comment: If I recall correctly, RAILS_ENV is always set so you can use that in RSPec as well. In addition, if you have other test environments, such as a test_ci one, you can do `if ENV["RAILS_ENV"] =~ /^test/`.